# How can I simulate subtraction operator on two binary numbers represented as strings?

Tags: c#, string, binary, subtraction

```
static string ReturnValueIfInputOneIsThirteenAndInputLengthIsEqualWithInputTwoLength(string input, string inputTwo)
        {
            string result = "";
            int temp = 0;
            int inputLength = input.Length - 1;
            int inputTwoLength = inputTwo.Length - 1;
            const int two = 2;

            while (inputLength >= 0 || inputTwoLength >= 0 || temp > 0)
            {
                temp += (inputLength >= 0) ? input[inputLength] - '0' : 0;
                temp += (inputTwoLength >= 0) ? inputTwo[inputTwoLength] - '0' : 0;
                result = (char)(temp % two + '0') + result;
                temp /= two;
                inputLength--;
                inputTwoLength--;
            }

            return result.TrimStart('0');
        }
```

I have to simulate somehow the subtraction operator on two binary numbers represented as strings. So I am asking for a suggestion that makes this happen without converting them to integers.

For example if I input 101 and 11 the result should be 10.

That's how I made for addition , but for subtraction I couldn't find a solution.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Search for `binary subtraction`, there are plenty of answers.

Comment: You could implement it like written subtraction on a piece of paper. The same procedure you've learned at school for decimal numbers also applies to binary numbers.

Comment: Yes I know I searched @aybe, but there were solutions that converted the two number to integers..

Comment: take the two's compliment of 11 which is 100 + 1 = 101.  Then add.